# Why can't I see my nav bar items?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I looked around for answers for this, but I couldn't find anything that helped. I am seeing my nav bar items in the scoreboard, but I can't see them when I run the simulator.

In the attributes inspector, with the bar button item selected I have "enabled" checked (not sure if that makes a difference)
[image: Imgur]

I have "Show Navigation Bar" selected on the navigation controller.
[image: Imgur]

Here is another screenshot of what it looks like in the simulator
[image: Imgur]

Comment: Post he screenshot about your nav bar in storyboard to offer more details.

Comment: @Leo posted pictures! Hopefully that helps a bit more!

Comment: you need to add a navbar state before, it is in the standard elements

Comment: @longbow what do you mean exactly? I have a navigation bar on the view controller, otherwise I wouldn't even be able to add a bar button item. Did you mean something else?

Comment: see answer, as i can not add picture to comment

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Navigation Item on Top of the Navbar.

[image]

And in there, you put your button.

Comment: Now I think I'm on the right path. I added what you said, then I placed my search bar button, but I still cannot see it for some reason

Comment: is your stuff present in the UI hierarchy? (button left from the triangle in the Debug Area)

Comment: Yes, it is. It's inside the navigation item as well.

Comment: just for testing, try to give it a title on the bar item and some image

Comment: Interesting. I added a title as well, and that did not show up in the simulator

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I completely understand your problem, but from what I can see, can you add the Navigation Item on the Navigation controller instead of the View Controller? Looking at your screenshot, the on eon the left is the Navigation Controller and on the right is the View Controller.

Simply drag the Navigation Bar Item and drop it on the Navigation Controller and select the search bar button. Check if this works.